# Receiving the error PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column mymodels.distance does not exist when using Geocoder's near method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, pg, rails-geocoder

When using this query (the same as in [Railscasts episode #273](http://railscasts.com/episodes/273-geocoder)):

```
@locations = Location.near(params[:search], 50, :order => :distance)
```

Or, to be more concise:

```
@mymodels = MyModel.near(address, distance, order: :distance)
```

I get the error:

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column mymodels.distance does not exist
```

The `distance` column is supposed to be added to the results by the [Geocoder gem](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) but it does not appear to appear in the results (so I get the above error).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using Postgres along with the [Geocoder gem](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder), your queries cannot use symbolized keys (in this case, `:distance`) in the query.  Using the string `'distance'` in this case avoids the problem.

```
@mymodels = MyModel.near(address, distance, order: 'distance')
```

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this (with rails 5.2.2) using:

```
@mymodels = Mymodel.where(publish: true).near(params[:search], 50, units: :km)
```